# Из несколько строк иерархии в одну строку

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

У меня есть иерархическая таблица с данными

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(
object_id varchar,
parent_id varchar
);

INSERT INTO my_table(object_id , parent_id)
VALUES
('1', '0'),
('2', '0'),
('3', '1'),
('4', '1'),
('5', '1'),
('6', '3'),
('7', '2'),
('8', '2');
```

Таблица 1
| object_id | parent_id |
| --------- | --------- |
|     1     |     0     |
|     2     |     0     |
|     3     |     1     |
|     4     |     1     |
|     5     |     1     |
|     6     |     3     |
|     7     |     2     |
|     8     |     2     |

Эти данные мне нужно трансформировать в такой результат:
Таблица2

| object_id | parent_id |
| --- | --- |
| {1,3,4,5,6},{2,7,8} | 0 |

Начал с текущего запроса, но пока не знаю куда дальше копать:

```
SELECT parent_id, array_to_string(array_agg(distinct(object_id)), ' , ', '') AS object_id
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY parent_id;
```

Предполагаю, что тут необходима промежуточная таблица

Всё это нужно, что бы посмотреть какие продукты купили пользователи.

В иерархической таблице есть список строк, который связан между собой через object_id и parent_id образуя иерархию, но и есть ИДи, у которых нету связей по parent_id в текущей таблицы - это есть парент (ид 0 таблица 1) с которой начинается связь. Далее после трансформации мне нужно получить результат Таблицы 2 для того, что бы его сджойнить с другой таблицей по ид 0.

Грубо говоря у меня есть таблица пользователей и есть таблица продуктов, где таблица продуктов может хранить в себе пакет продуктов(иерархию), допустим пакет "студенческий" это продукт, в который входит сыр, масло и т.д., этот пакет имеет object_id 1, а parent_id 0 (это ид пользователя), object_id 3 это сыр и т.д.

Comment: Можете пояснить логику, как из этой таблицы и почему должен получиться такой результат?

Comment: *Эти данные мне нужно трансформировать в такой результат* Судя по изображению, требуется массив массивов. А такого типа в Постгрессе - нет. Определите ТОЧНО тип данных в требуемом результате.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS (
  SELECT object_id, parent_id, object_id root_id
  FROM test
  WHERE parent_id = '0'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT test.object_id, test.parent_id, cte.root_id
  FROM cte
  JOIN test ON cte.object_id = test.parent_id
),
cte2 AS (
  SELECT '{' || ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(object_id), ',') || '}' object_id
  FROM cte
  GROUP BY root_id
)
SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(object_id), ',') object_id, 0 parent_id 
FROM cte2
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/MkaZiUzZ

Comment: Спасибо! Чуть переделал для себя, только вместо обычных цифр начал использовать uuid и у меня во второй рекурсии такое ощущение, что идёт сортировка по object_id во время применения distinct (12 строка)
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/875f2/1
если дистинкт убираю, то всё вроде бы ок, но у меня могут дублироваться некоторые строки в исходной таблице

Comment: @Maxim *у меня во второй рекурсии такое ощущение, что идёт сортировка по object_id* Там сортировки нет вообще, так что порядок записей в группе в высшей степени отфонарный. Но DISTINCT выполняется через сортировку - так что неудивительно. Если нужен какой-то другой порядок - добавь WITHIN GROUP ORDER BY. Кстати, а нафига он был нужен, этот DISTINCT? запрос не должен давать дубликатов..

Comment: я понимаю, что нет сортировки, но для меня немного загадачно, почему если дистинкт использую, то очерёдность другая становится

Comment: @Maxim DISTINCT - удаление дубликатов. Максимально эффективно он выполняется через сортировку.

Comment: понял, спасибо!

Comment: Используя рекурсию в CTE при бизнес логике вынесенной за пределы зоны ответственности базы  нужно добавить контроль зацикленности ссылок, иначе ваш запрос может уйти в бесконечный цикл, не по вашей вине, но кому это интересно. (https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/14/queries-with)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте брутфорсом с примером отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39212832/how-to-aggregate-two-postgresql-columns-to-an-array-separated-by-brackets. Ситуация очень похожа, на мой взгляд. Вдруг поможет...

Comment: Логика вашего объединения мне осталась не ясна. Поэтому по-другому пока не ответить